# NullPointerException: thrown in OnMapReady method

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, google-nearby

Started running my google maps project and encountered this  NullPointerException error in the 
Logcat ->

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.sachiewerk.smart_healthcare.pharma2.onMapReady(pharma2.java:100)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:504)
    at fr.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12688021@12.6.88 (040306-197970725):20)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12688021@12.6.88 (040306-197970725):5)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12688021@12.6.88 (040306-197970725):5)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

The app finds and displays nearby pharmacies, This class show details of nearby pharmacy details like(address, phone numbers, website URI and price ratings) in a custom info window.

this is the class java code

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sachiewerk.smart_healthcare.models.PlaceInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class pharma2 extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
       GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready..");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }




            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            buildGoogleApiClient();

            init();

        }

/*
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        Button btnPharma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPharma);
        btnPharma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            String search = "pharmacy";

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){

                mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, search);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                GetNearbyBanksData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyBanksData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(pharma2.this, "These are your Nearby Pharmacies! ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    /*
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    }


    private static final String TAG = "pharma2";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 20f;
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-40, -168), new LatLng(71, 136));

    //widgets
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;
    private ImageView mInfo;
    private ImageView mPlacePicker;



    //vars
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceInfo mPlace;
    private Marker mMarker;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    double latitude, longitude;
    private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hosp2);
        mSearchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);
        mInfo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.place_info);
        mPlacePicker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.place_picker);



        getLocationPermission();

    }


    private void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "init: initializing");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

        mSearchText.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);


        mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, Places.getGeoDataClient(this, null),
                LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);


        mSearchText.setAdapter(mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
            mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                            || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                            || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                            || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                        //execute our method for searching
                        geolocate();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        mInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked place Info");
                try {
                    if (mMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                        mMarker.hideInfoWindow();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: place info: " + mPlace.toString());
                        mMarker.showInfoWindow();
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClick: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        });

        mPlacePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(builder.build(pharma2.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClick: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClick: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, place.getId());
                placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private void geolocate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "geolocate: geolocating");

        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(pharma2.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "geolocate: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (list.size() > 0) {
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "geolocate: found a location: " + address.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }
    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {
        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new
                StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyAvxiw4FVJzY-XGx9mW8fNde4bjvc8mlbo");
        return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    }


     /*
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */



    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting device's current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM, "Your Device's Location");

                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(pharma2.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, PlaceInfo placeInfo) {
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        mMap.clear();

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(pharma2.this));

        if (placeInfo != null) {
            try {
                String snippet = "Address: " + placeInfo.getAddress() + "\n" +
                        "Phone Number: " + placeInfo.getPhoneNumber() + "\n" +
                        "Website: " + placeInfo.getWebsiteUri() + "\n" +
                        "Rating: " + placeInfo.getRating() + "\n";

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(placeInfo.getName())
                        .snippet(snippet);

                mMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "moveCamera: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        }

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title) {
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        if (!title.equals("My Location")) {
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);
            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }


    private void initMap() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map..");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(pharma2.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                initMap();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called");

        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;

                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    //initialize map
                    initMap();

                }
            }
        }


    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        0).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }


    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /*
    ----------------------Google Places Autocomplete suggesstions-------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
            hideSoftKeyboard();
            final AutocompletePrediction item = mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter.getItem(i);
            final String placeId = item.getPlaceId();

            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient ,placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if(!places.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: PLace query did not complete successfully: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                places.release();
                return;
            }
            final Place place = places.get(0);

            try{
                mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
                mPlace.setName(place.getName().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: name: " + place.getName());
                mPlace.setAddress(place.getAddress().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: address: " + place.getAddress());
                //      mPlace.setAttribution(place.getAttributions().toString());
                //     Log.d(TAG, "onResult: attribution: " + place.getAttributions());
                mPlace.setId(place.getId());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: id: " + place.getId());
                mPlace.setLatLng(place.getLatLng());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: latlng: " + place.getLatLng());
                mPlace.setRating(place.getRating());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: rating: " + place.getRating());
                mPlace.setPhoneNumber(place.getPhoneNumber().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Phone Number:" + place.getPhoneNumber());
                mPlace.setWebsiteUri(place.getWebsiteUri());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Website: " + place.getWebsiteUri());

                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: place: " + mPlace.toString());
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            moveCamera(new LatLng(place.getViewport().getCenter().latitude,
                    place.getViewport().getCenter().longitude), DEFAULT_ZOOM, mPlace);

            places.release();

        }
    };




    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mMarker != null) {
            mMarker.remove();
        }


        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("You are Here!");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
        Toast.makeText(pharma2.this, "Your Current Location",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Really want to get this app to work because it is my end of year project for my java class. 
Any help will much appreciated.

Comment: Can you debug your code form these lines :

Button btnPharma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPharma);

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because you're calling the method `OnMapReady()` before creating the view in the `OnCreate()` method. Besides, you're not calling the method `initMap()` anywhere.

Comment: I called initMap() in the getLocationPermission() method.

Answer (score 0):

i think you got error on this part.

```
Button btnPharma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPharma);
btnPharma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){});
```

Your `activity_hosp2.xml` doesn't have `btnPharma` id, thus it got 
`Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference`
when you try to listener to null object.